# Parsing XML Attributes with NSXMLParser

Tags: xcode, uitableview, attributes, nsxmlparser

Im searching to parse all the attributes "unit1" and "unit2" from the N tags of this simplified xml file, and then put them in a UITableView:

```
<xml>
<meta></meta>
<time1>
<product>
<value1 id="id1Time1" unit1="unit1Time1" number1="number1Time1"/>
<value2 id="id2Time1" unit2="unit2Time1" number2="number2Time1"/>
</product>
</time1>
<time2>
<product>
<value1 id="id1Time2" unit1="unit1Time2" number1="number1Time2"/>
<value2 id="id2Time2" unit2="unit2Time2" number2="number2Time2"/>
</product>
</time2>
...
<timeN>
<product>
<value1 id="id1TimeN" unit1="unit1TimeN" number1="number1TimeN"/>
<value2 id="id2TimeN" unit2="unit2TimeN" number2="number2TimeN"/>
</product>
</timeN>
</xml>
```

I'm using NSXMLParser, self delegate, and I'm using this code:

```
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict{
    currentElement = [elementName copy];
    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"value1"]) {
        arrayUnit1 = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init]; 
        stringUnit1 = [attributeDict objectForKey:@"unit1"];
        [arrayUnit1 addObject:stringUnit1];
    }
    if
        ([elementName isEqualToString:@"value2"]) {
        arrayUnit2 = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        stringUnit2 = [attributeDict objectForKey:@"unit2"];
        [arrayUnit2 addObject:stringUnit2];
    }
}
```

To populate UITableView with value1 and value2 I'm using:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return [arrayUnit1 count]; // <--- I Know, here is the problem!
}
```

...

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell"];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:
                UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:@"Cell"];
    }

    cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[arrayUnit1 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[arrayUnit2 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];

    return cell;
}
```

Well, the parsing is perfect, I can also NSLog every N stringValues but in my UITableView I can see ONLY ONE row with the LAST values of arrayUnit N (in this example unit1TimeN and unit2TimeN). So how can I populate the table with EVERY value, all the N values of my arrays? Maybe I need to implement also - (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:? Thanks!

Comment: is `value1` in code same as `number1` in xml?

Comment: Sorry, I've now edited, value1 is value1... ;=)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

remove this line from here

> arrayUnit1 = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

and put it some where else when you allocate the parser.. 
this is removing all previous elements of the array and allocing it new memory, so you will only see the last element added..

Answer (score 0):

You are reallocating a new array at every parsed element, just allocate the arrays once:

```
if (!arrayUnit1)
   arrayUnit1 = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```